# how to ignore comments when writing to yaml python

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file that includes comments like

```
#hello

KB_PROJECT = MHV
```

I am adding data using yaml library to this file .. and then dump

it is removing the #hello

which is not good for me

Comment: Ignoring comments as in your title means to me you don't want them, but from your text it looks like you want to preserve them. So what is it. You should include a minimal program, so we can see what you are doing wroing as ruamel.yaml should preserve comments when using the (default) round-trip mode, although it might not if you indeed have only a single scalar string as data in your YAML document (as per example).

Comment: No .. Actually I want to keep them ,, I understand you .. my intellij does not recognize the ruamel , I understand it preserves the comments so will try to fix this